# Spring Security - Preventing Users access to a page if an id is invalid

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security and am mulling over the idea of using it or not in my application.
The requirement is as follows :

1. In my web application i store a session information inside the database,a key for this is stored in a cookie
   2.Now whenever someone tries to access a url which is not according to the flow i want to deny access.
   3.Can i use Spring Security for this.

I am using Spring MVC,Mongo DB and MySQL as the develeoment environment.

Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: Are you trying to control the flow, or restrict certain flows by access group?

Comment: I am trying to control the flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to simply control the flow of an application, I'd suggest using Spring Webflow. This allows you to define set flows in a multi-page application.

Spring Security can be used to control flows, but only for access control. It integrates well with Webflow (and with Spring MVC) to ensure you can secure some or all of your flows.